# Count being filtered incorrectly and not sure why

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to get the count of individuals with multiple "booking events" that have T1 or T2 charges on record. In the screenshot, you can see that correct count should be 5.

[image]

The following measure has correctly provided me with the count of unique individuals with multiple booking events (16). I am not trying to modify this measure to get me the count of unique individuals with multiple booking events that have T1 or T2 charges associated with them.

```
# Individuals w/ Multiple Arrests = 

VAR tbl =
    SUMMARIZE(
        factBookingCharge,
        factBookingCharge[fkEmployee],
        "Arrests", DISTINCTCOUNT(dimBookingEvent[BookingSystemId])
    )
VAR individualsMultipleArrest = CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(factBookingCharge[fkEmployee]),
    FILTER(
        tbl,
        [Arrests] > 1
    )
)

RETURN
    individualsMultipleArrest
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by creating a new measure and then using that new measure as a filter within the "tbl" context. I am still curious if there was a better way to handle this. Still new to PBI and DAX so any other solutions would be great help to me. Thanks!

```
Has T1 or T2 Charges = IF(CALCULATE(COUNT(factBookingCharge[fkEmployee]), dimTier[ShortDescription] = "1" || dimTier[ShortDescription] = "2") >=1, "True", "False")

# Individuals w/ Multiple Arrests and T1/T2 Charges = 

VAR tbl =
    SUMMARIZE(
        factBookingCharge,
        factBookingCharge[fkEmployee],
        "Arrests", DISTINCTCOUNT(dimBookingEvent[BookingSystemId])
    )
VAR individualsMultipleArrest = CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(factBookingCharge[fkEmployee]),
    FILTER(
        tbl,
        [Arrests] > 1 && [Has T1 or T2 Charges] 
    )
)

RETURN
    individualsMultipleArrest
```